# SQL to receive a sum of values and that values separates by one ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have the tables `AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT` and `TIPOACTIVO` in two different databases (SQL Server and Oracle)

`AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT`:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id_activo|impacto_Total|id_Dimension|riesgo_Total|version_jpa|id_TipoActivo|
|---------|-------------|------------|------------|-----------|-------------|
|    3    |      0      |    1       |     0      |    0      |    1        |
|    3    |    10000    |    2       |   1000     |    1      |    1        |
|    3    |     2000    |    3       |     0      |    1      |    1        |
|    3    |     1000    |    4       |    550     |    0      |    1        |
|    3    |     125     |    5       |    500     |    0      |    1        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`TIPOACTIVO`:

```
------------------------
|id_tipoActivo| nombre |
|-------------|--------|
|     1       | algo   |
------------------------
```

Currently I use this query to extract the `id_activo` 3 with a sum of `riesgo_Total` using all dimensions (1000+550+500 = 2550).

Now i need to extract the sum and the `sum(riesgo_Total)` of all dimensions and every dimension separated but all in the same query.

Until today I used these queries:

```
// Query to get all riesgo_total (of all dimensions).
SELECT T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO, SUM(RIESGO_TOTAL) AS RIESGO_TOTAL 
FROM AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT T JOIN TIPO_ACTIVO TA ON (T.ID_TIPOACTIVO = TA.ID_TIPOACTIVO) 
WHERE RIESGO_TOTAL>0
GROUP BY T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO 
ORDER BY RIESGO_TOTAL DESC

// Query to get riesgo_total of id_dimension = 1.
SELECT T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO, SUM(RIESGO_TOTAL) AS RIESGO_TOTAL 
FROM AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT T JOIN TIPO_ACTIVO TA ON (T.ID_TIPOACTIVO = TA.ID_TIPOACTIVO) 
WHERE RIESGO_TOTAL>0 AND ID_DIMENSION = '1'
GROUP BY T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO 
ORDER BY RIESGO_TOTAL DESC
```

How can obtain a result like

```
AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT = T
TIPOACTIVO = TA

|T.ID_ACTIVO | TA.NOMBRE | Riesgo_total (all dimension) | riesgo_total (id_dimension = 1) | riesgo_total (id_dimension = 2) | riesgo_total (id_dimension = 3) | riesgo_total (id_dimension = 4) |  riesgo_total (id_dimension = 5) |
|------------|-----------|------------------------------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|----------------------------------|
|     3      |  algo     |        2550                  |               0                 |              1000               |            0                    |             550                 |                500               |
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i tried to use subquerys but every time i get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case statement inside your sum to get the sums of the individual dimensions

```
SELECT T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO, SUM(RIESGO_TOTAL) AS RIESGO_TOTAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN id_Dimension = 1 THEN riesgo_Total ELSE 0 END) AS RIESGO_TOTAL_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN id_Dimension = 2 THEN riesgo_Total ELSE 0 END) AS RIESGO_TOTAL_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN id_Dimension = 3 THEN riesgo_Total ELSE 0 END) AS RIESGO_TOTAL_3,
SUM(CASE WHEN id_Dimension = 4 THEN riesgo_Total ELSE 0 END) AS RIESGO_TOTAL_4,
SUM(CASE WHEN id_Dimension = 5 THEN riesgo_Total ELSE 0 END) AS RIESGO_TOTAL_5
FROM AGR_IMP_TOTAL_ACT T JOIN TIPO_ACTIVO TA ON (T.ID_TIPOACTIVO = TA.ID_TIPOACTIVO) 
WHERE RIESGO_TOTAL>0
GROUP BY T.ID_TIPOACTIVO, TA.NOMBRE, T.ID_ACTIVO 
ORDER BY RIESGO_TOTAL DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly. now i discover that i can use methods inside other methods.